# Displaying data from two collections using each block

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

So I have 2 collections as follows
Collection user, a document might look like this

```
{_"id":"xyz",
"name":"sam"
}
```

Collection items, more that one documents linked to user collection as follows

```
{_"id":"123345",
   "userid":"xyz"
    "item":"potato"
}
{_"id":"3456",
   "userid":"xyz"
    "item":"tomato"
}
```

now lets say i am running a query to display all documents with name sam as follows, (will be run as a helper)

```
return User.find({name:"sam"});
```

and I pass the records into blaze template and display value using {{#each}}.

Now, additionally I want to also display data from collection "items" along with collection "users". So my data in html after using {{#each}} might look like this

```
<li> sam ...potato, tomato </li>
<li> sam ...potato, tomato, orange </li> 
<li> sam ...pineapple </li>  
<li> sam ... </li>
```

i.e data is being displayed on the template using #each but from 2 different collections.

Can anyone tell me how the code in my template should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [publish-composite package](https://github.com/englue/meteor-publish-composite) when you make your users publication. (See example 1 in the link)

So for your use case something like should work:

```
Meteor.publishComposite('userItems', {
      find: function() {
         return Users.find({
               name: "sam"
           },
           {
               sort: {
               ...
            },
               fields: {
               ...
            }
         });
       },
      children: [{
            find: function(user) {
               return Items.find({
                 userid: user._id
            }, {
                fields: {
                   "item": true,
                   ...
               }
            });
      }}]
```

});

Comment: I used the package that you mentioned, and it works like a charm.

On the client side I used this._id as mentioned in the comment below.

Answer (score 1):

The solution here is to pass a parameter to the helper. Here it should happen a little bit trickier:

1)Know how to pass parameters:

lets name the helper products

> HTML

```
{{products paramA}}
```

> JS

```
products: function(userId){
findOne({userId:userId})
}
```

2)Perfect, but how to pass the `_id`:

As you are calling the users helper with `each` you have access by `{{_id}}` so it should be possible to pass it.
If this somehow does not work. Again try to use the `each`. Try to reach the element in the products helper by `this._id`.

I hope the two ways will be enough to solve your problem.